# I can't understand the result of this chatting program

Tags: c, scanf, fifo

So I made a simple server-client program that can communicate with each other using fifo file (msgfifo).

My question is: When I type a message which includes a space, the receiver process runs several times with number of words.

That's not I expected, as I expected to print it out as a whole sentence, but it doesn't, and I want to know why.

When I type a something to send, process send SIGUSR1 signal to another.

```
/* receive msg part */
/* added this using sigset(SIGUSR1, receiveSIGUSR1) */

void receiveSIGUSR1()
{
    char* msg = "\nIncoming Message from client...";
    char* msg2 = "\nClient : ";
    char buf[max_of_msg];
    int fd;
    write(1, msg, strlen(msg)+1);
    fflush(stdin);
    if( (fd = open("./msgpipe", O_RDONLY)) < 0)
    {   perror("open"); exit(1);    }
    read(fd, buf, max_of_msg);
    close(fd);
    write(1, msg2, strlen(msg2)+1);
    write(1, buf, strlen(buf)+1);
    flag = 0;
}

/*send msg part*/

while(1)
{
    flag = -1;
    printf("\nType what u want to send : ");
    scanf(" %s", msg);
    if(flag == 0)   continue;
    printf("msgtaken\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    if( (fd = open("./msgpipe", O_RDWR)) < 0)
    {   perror("exit"); exit(1);    }
    kill(clpid, 30);
    sleep(2);
    printf("Send message to Client..\n");
    write(fd, msg, max_of_msg);
    printf("Message Sent...\n");
}
```

Expected:

> Client : Hello Server this is client

Actual:
/* server */

> Incoming Message from client... 
> Hello 
> Incoming Message
>   from client... 
> this 
> Incoming Message from client... 
> is
>   
> Incoming Message from client... 
> client 
>  
> Type what u
>   want to send :

/*client*/

> Type what u want to send : Hello Server This is client
>   
> msgtaken 
> Send message to server.. 
> Message sent 
>   
> Type what u want to send : msgtaken 
> Send message to server..
>   
> Message sent 
>  
> Type what u want to send : msgtaken 
> Send
>   message to server.. 
> Message sent 
>  
> Type what u want to send
>   : msgtaken 
> Send message to server.. 
> Message sent 
>  
> Type
>   what u want to send : msgtaken 
> Send message to server..
>   
> Message sent
>
> Type what u want to send :

Comment: Why are you mixing `read`, `write`, and `scanf`?  Pick a family and stick to it.  Or, use a more general rule of thumb; don't use `scanf`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell ok thanks for your advise.

Comment: Side note: The functions `fflush()`, `perror()`, and `exit()` are not safe to call from a signal handler. See http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html for details and a list of what functions are okay to use. Also, `fflush()` on an input stream like `stdin` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because this is how it takes input:

```
scanf(" %s", msg);
```

Let's have a look at the documentation of [`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) (emphasis mine):

> s: Any number of non-whitespace characters, **stopping at the first
>   whitespace character found**. A terminating null character is
>   automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.

That's why it stops after `Hello` when you send `Hello Server this is client`. Also note the space in `" %s"`, this means that it will also ignore any whitespace at the start of the input. So when it reads the `Server` on the next run through the loop, this makes it ignore the space between `Hello` and `Server`. As a result, it goes through the loop five times, and the messages each time are `Hello`, `Server`, `this`, `is` and `client`.

Instead, you could use [`getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/getline):

```
char *message = NULL;
size_t length;
getline(&message, &length, stdin);
// use message
free(message);
```

---

A little side note: to make your `scanf` call more safe, you can specify a maximum size for the string input:

```
scanf(" %99s", msg);
```

Per example, this would mean that only 99 `char` can be read in, plus a null terminator, for a buffer size of 100. This way you can avoid undefined behavior that would occur if the user would enter a string that is too big for your buffer.